# .NET Core 2.1 : How to trigger Copy task defined in the project file during debugging in the Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

There are some files residing in other directories that, I would like to copy to project folder automatically before build and publishing.

After some research and experimentation, I have come up with the following .csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <TieredCompilation>true</TieredCompilation>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <APIDefinition Include="D:\SomePlace\*.API.*.yaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Compile;Build;Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(APIDefinition)" DestinationFolder="wwwroot" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="D:\SomePlaceElse\BaseAPISettings.json" DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\**\*;node_modules;bower_components" />
    <None Update="**.user;**.vspscc">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here I have defined CopyFiles target, which should be run before the targets I've placed there. This target uses Copy task to copy YAML format API definition files and base API settings to the project directory.

This works well during build, publish etc. Also, if I delete the local file in the IDE, it instantly recopies it from the source.

Sometimes I make changes to these files between debugging sessions. Then, when I start debugging from Visual Studio, since the project files aren't changed, obviously the already built project is run.

Since the project is not built, my copy tasks are not triggered, and I end up with stale files during debuging.

Is there anything I can do to have my Copy tasks triggered, when I do "Start Debugging F5" in the IDE, regardless of the project build state ?

P.S. : I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.8.5 and targeting .NET Core 2.1.4 runtime, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To integrate fully into the up-to-date check of the project system inside Visual Studio, I susggest the following changes:

1. Make the items' source and target paths known before
2. Register them to the up-to-date check system. (Also needs a hack to make sure the project source code is recompiled so that the output will have a newer time stamp)
3. Make the MSBuild target itself incremental. This also helps for command-line builds when the files don't have to be copied.

The complete changes look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <CustomCopyFile Include="..\TestFiles\*.API.*.yaml"
                  TargetPath="wwwroot\%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  <CustomCopyFile Include="..\TestFiles\BaseAPISettings.json"
                  TargetPath="%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  <UpToDateCheckInput Include="@(CustomCopyFile)" />
  <UpToDateCheckBuild Include="@(CustomCopyFile->'%(TargetPath)')"
                      Original="@(CustomCopyFile)" />
  <CustomAdditionalCompileInputs Include="@(CustomCopyFile->'%(TargetPath)')" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles" 
        BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforePublish"
        Inputs="@(CustomCopyFile)" 
        Outputs="@(CustomCopyFile->'%(TargetPath)')">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(CustomCopyFile)"
        DestinationFiles="@(CustomCopyFile->'%(TargetPath)')" />
</Target>
```

`CustomCopyFile` now collects all the source files and we put the expected destination file name into the `TargetPath` metadata.

`UpToDateCheckInput` items tell Visual Studio to rebuild the project if one of these items change.

`UpToDateCheckBuild` items instruct Visual Studio to only check these items against special source items. This is redundant for this example project but may be helpful if the target path wasn't inside the project directory but some intermediate output  (obj..) folder and no re-evaluation would see these new files. It would also be helpful if the files were also modified as part of processing (e.g. replacing variables inside the files).

`CustomAdditionalCompileInputs` is a hack here since the items are copied to the project folder and are considered to be "inputs to the output" automatically.. So we force the project to recompile if our source files change. If we don't do so, it would never consider the project up-to-date after a change to the source yaml files since they would be newer than the compiled app.dll file.

Comment: My hat's off to you, sir. This really is an excellent answer, thank you. Not only you've provided a solution, but you've also explained how and why it works. You also went to the trouble of incorporating my files into your solution. It worked beautifully at the first try, just by copying your solution and pasting it into my .csproj file. Also, I think I have a use for UpToDateCheckBuild, because I was thinking of modifiying parts of the yaml files before publish. Microsoft support has a few things to learn from you, really. Cheers.

Comment: Documentation is scarce, but from what I can see it should actually be `UpToDateCheckBuilt`, not `UpToDateCheckBuild`.

Comment: One issue I've found with this solution is that it doesn't seem to cause the build to run unless both the input and output files exist, and the input file is newer. If you delete the output files for example, or add a new input file without invalidating your build in some other way, the CopyFiles target still won't execute, at least when compiling through the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: @RogerSanders do you have a repro or does that happen with the sample code here? might be worth opening an issue on dotnet/project-system on GitHub. MSBuild does respect missing outputs..

Comment: @MartinUllrich I think it's actually my mistake, I was applying this to a C++ project and forgot when I wrote this that the answer was in the context of .Net Core. Despite this, the solution "mostly works" in this context, but the `CustomAdditionalCompileInputs` hook in particular I know doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: yes c++ targets are different and it uses a different project system inside of VS so nothing of this q&a apply here

Comment: @RogerSanders Is correct, UpToDateCheckBuild is misspelled. As a side note, I've found that the UpToDateCheckInput CustomAdditionalCompileInputs combo above doesn't always work perfectly. Occasionally when you change a source file, fast-up-do-date check invokes msbuild on the first build, and on the next build, and only the third time decides the project is up to date. Once I noticed Roger's comment, I changed the spelling of UpToDateCheckBuild to UpToDateCheckBuilt, removed the other two (UpToDateCheckInput and CustomAdditionalCompileInputs), and it appears to work perfectly now.